# jQuery loading external pages in a html tag after removing a class attribute

Tags: jquery, load

I have a problem. In my main page, i have the following code

```
<script>
window.ctrl = <?php echo $ctrl; ?> // this return false or true  
if (! window.ctrl) { 
   $('.grCtrl').remove() 
}
var le = 'somePage.php';
$('#loadingDiv').load(le);
</script>

<div id='originalDiv'>
   <h3>
      Original div is  
      <span class='grCtrl'>this</span> 
    </h3>
</div>

<div id='loadingDiv'></div>
```

And now somepage.php:

```
<div id='somePageDiv'>
    <h3>
      Loaded div is
      <span class='grCtrl'>this</span> 
    </h3>
</div>
```

So the problem is that in original div (in main page), remove() method is working but not working in the loaded page in #loadingDiv.

If someone can explain me why so I'll be obliged.
Thank you.
Leo

Comment: so are you expecting your code to remove an element that hasn't yet been loaded into the DOM? just place the remove after the load and it should work

Comment: well as you said its dynamically loaded content so you need to use event delegation.... `.on()` or `.live()` or `.delegate()` or `.bind()`....i prefer `.on()` as other are deprecated from newer version.

Comment: upss :| ... I see now :( I'm so tired. Shame on me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because it is being loaded after you are running the remove.

Try this.

```
<script>
window.ctrl = <?php echo $ctrl; ?> // this return false or true  
if (! window.ctrl) { 
   $('.grCtrl').remove() 
}
var le = 'somePage.php';
$('#loadingDiv').load(le, function(){
    if (! window.ctrl) { 
        $('.grCtrl').remove() 
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: well we can make a use of event delegation instead of repeating same code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this answer but I use event delegation as @Dipesh suggested.

Comment: @DipeshParmar You make a compelling point but can we perhaps see an example?